# Rename [foundation]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I think the tag [foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation) should be renamed, because it keeps getting confused with [zurb-foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation). In fact, among the questions that are tagged with [foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation) (the Objective-C library), most are actually about [zurb-foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) (the web front-end framework).

Thus, I propose to rename [foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation) to [foundation-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation-kit) or [foundation-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foundation-objective-c). Any thoughts?

Comment: I have moved all the Zurb Foundation questions to [zurb-foundation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) using other tags html, css, javascript, jquery, wordpress and a keyword search to catch a few stragglers.  There were less than 100 that I found that way.  I'm going to add a reference to the tag wiki to direct users.

Comment: I support this.  It's 2017, and I've been editing/flagging about one non-FoundationKit "foundation" post a day.  The vast majority of questions tagged "foundation" in the past few months (say about 90%) have not been about FoundationKit.  It's not hard to find old mis-tagged questions, either.  "Foundation" is such a generic term that it's used for at least 3 common yet completely different technologies, and it's probably best if none of them get the bare word.

Comment: FoundationKit isn't just used from ObjC any more, so "foundation-kit" makes the most sense to me.  I'm not sure what the situation on Windows is, but there seem to be a lot of things named "Windows ___ Foundation".  If it's useful to keep those around, we should get a Windows expert to chime in with a suggestion.